# Tensorflow: binary mask of max values along tensor axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

If I have a N-dimensional tensor, I would like to create another tensor (with the same shape) of values 0 and 1, where 1 is in the same position as the maximum element in original tensor across some dimension. 
One constraint I have is that I want to get only the **first maximum element** along that axis, in case there are duplicates.

For simplification, I will use fewer dimensions.

```py
>>> x = tf.constant([[7, 2, 3], 
                     [5, 0, 1], 
                     [3, 8, 2]], dtype=tf.float32)

>>> tf.reduce_max(x, axis=-1)
tf.Tensor([7. 5. 8.], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
```

What I want is:

```python
tf.Tensor([1. 0. 0.], 
          [1. 0. 0.],
          [0. 1. 0.], shape=(3,3), dtype=float32)
```

What I've tried (and realized was wrong):

```python
>>> tf.cast(tf.equal(x, tf.reduce_max(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)), dtype=tf.float32)

# works fine when there are no duplicates
tf.Tensor([[1. 0. 0.]
           [1. 0. 0.]
           [0. 1. 0.]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)


>>> y = tf.zeros([3,3])
>>> tf.cast(tf.equal(y, tf.reduce_max(y, axis=-1, keepdims=True)), dtype=tf.float32)

# fails when there are multiple identical values across dimension
tf.Tensor([[1. 1. 1.]
           [1. 1. 1.]
           [1. 1. 1.]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)
```

**Edit: Solved**

```python
tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argsort(tf.argsort(x, 1, direction='DESCENDING'), 1), 0), tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use double `tf.argsort()` to get rank order of elements along axis 1 and get max rank. This gives the `last` instance of the max value as the top rank. Let's take an example with duplicate elements -

```
x = tf.constant([[7, 2, 3],  #max is 7
                 [5, 0, 5],  #max is 5 but duplicate in same row
                 [7, 8, 7]]) #max is 8 but shares 7 with first row too

tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argsort(tf.argsort(x, 1), 1), x.shape[0]-1), tf.int64)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood: I don't want duplicate elements, so in your example, only the first element of the second row should be one.

Comment: Updated my solution to mark only a single value per row as max when duplicate occur. Only condition is that it marks the last one as the max one, instead of the first. of thats ok with you. let me know.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I made some adjustment so it marks the first element, as you can see in my edit.